Disable or hide Return to classic in Sharepoint Server 2019 on premise
In my publishing site, I need to hide "Return to Classic SharePoint". I have a document library set to modern view, but users can see the option "Return to classic Sharepoint". How to hide this from users? 

Please use SharePoint Online Management Shell to run the following command to hide this option.
Download link: SharePoint Online Management Shell
Get Start: Get started with SharePoint Online Management Shell
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url https://Crescent-Admin.sharepoint.com
 
#Disable "Return to Classic SharePoint"
Set-SPOTenant -DisableBackToClassic $True

Please use the SharePoint global administrator account.

I have Sharepoint server 2019 on premise not Sharepoint Online.
